# Proof that the product of $L$-function over all Dirichlet characters is not less than 1 (from Fourier Analysis by Stein)

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

On page 266 of Fourier Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, it is shown that

> If $s > 1$, then $$\prod_{\chi} L(s,\chi)\geq 1,$$ where the product is taken over all Dirichlet characters. In particular the product is real-valued.

The sketch of the proof is to rewrite $L(s,\chi)$ using Dirichlet's product formula.
$$\begin{aligned}
\prod_{\chi} L(s, \chi)&= \exp\left(\sum_{\chi}\sum_p \log_1\left(\frac{1}{1 - \chi(p)p^{-s}}\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\sum_\chi \sum_p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\frac{\chi(p^k)}{p^{ks}}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_\chi \frac{1}{k}\frac{\chi(p^k)}{p^{ks}}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\varphi(q)\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\frac{\delta_0(p^k)}{p^{ks}}\right) \geq 1
\end{aligned}$$
since the terms inside the exponential are non-negative.

A lemma that is used:

> The Dirichlet characters are multiplicative. Moreover,
> $$\delta_l(m) = \frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_\chi \overline{\chi(l)}\chi(m),$$
> where the sum is over all Dirichlet characters.

---

Some clarification for notations:

1. $\log_1$ is a function defined as $$\log_1\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}\quad\text{for } |z|<1.$$
2. $p$ takes value from all prime numbers.
3. $\chi(\cdot)$ is the Dirichlet character.
4. $\varphi(q)$ is the order of group $\mathbb{Z}^*(q)$.
5. $\delta_l(n) = \mathbb{I}(n\equiv l\pmod q)$.

---

My question is regarding the last equation in the proof, where the book says with $l = 0$, the lemma gives $\sum_\chi \chi(p^k) = \varphi(q)\delta_0(p^k)$. To get this from the lemma, I would assume that $\chi(0) = 1$. However, should not $\chi(0) = 0$ since $0$ is never relatively prime to $q$? Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn’t it $\delta_1$ actually?

Comment: Ahh yeah, I think it makes sense to be $\delta_1$. It was $\delta_0$ in the book and it explicitly says with $l = 0$, so that is why I got confused. Thank you for pointing that out!